# Derivation of the upper convected time derivative

Tags: polymers, soft-matter, rheology

I read on wikipedia theat the upper convected time derivatvie is the rate of change of some tensor property of a small parcelof fluid that is written in the coordinate system rotating and stretching with the fluid. But concretely how do we obtain its expression ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want more details on how this derivation works, [this work](http://www.math.wisc.edu/~spagnolie/Papers/Introduction_to_Complex_Fluids.pdf) is a great resource. Look specifically at Page 23 onwards. If you have any specific question about the derivation, feel free to ask me and I can go through some of it for you.

Hope that helps!

Comment: That's a nice paper.